# How to sum specific rows using awk and other methods?

Tags: grep, awk

```
123|Raghu|80|90|60

234|Maya|10|20|30

123|Atul|20|30|60

413|Gita|56|71|89

745|Mohan|22|100|23
```

This is my text file where I need to sum the marks of each student and print them line by line.

Comment: Let's see what you want it to look like!

Comment: Raghu 230 and so on for other names

Answer (score 0):

You don't need awk for this, a bash script will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='|'
while read -r -a array line
do
  i=0;sum=0;line=""
  for element in "${array[@]}"
  do
    if [ $i -gt 1 ]
    then
      let sum=sum+$element        
    else
      line=$line$element$IFS
    fi
    let i=i+1
  done
  echo "$line$sum"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

If the above script is called process and your data file is called data, running

```
process < data
```

will produce

```
123|Raghu|230
234|Maya|60
123|Atul|110
413|Gita|216
745|Mohan|145
```